# Transforming a frequency incidence matrix for community detection

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory

I have a two mutually exclusive sets *A* and *B*, containing *n* and *p* concepts respectively. With these, I build an *n x p* incidence matrix, where the entries contain counts describing how many times a given pair of concepts of *A* and *B* has occurred. These relationships are not directed.

I want to build a bipartite graph with this matrix and do community detection over it. For example:

```
library(igraph)
incidence.matrix <- structure(c(10, 1, 1, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 29, 0, 1, 0, 7, 69, 
3, 7, 0, 22), .Dim = c(5L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("A1", "A2", 
"A3", "A4", "A5"), c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4")))

g <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(incidence.matrix, directed = FALSE, multiple = FALSE, weighted = TRUE)
```

However, as I understand, the values on the incidence matrix do not represent edge weights because they are frequencies (in a way, giving information about similarity rather than a cost between a pair of nodes).

Is transforming the incidence matrix into a cost matrix necessary for all community detection algorithms, or are there some of them that can work with the counts matrix? If transforming the values into cost is necessary, what is a reasonable way to do this?